# How to remove Play-store notification "uninstall harmful app"? (kit-kat)

Tags: google-play-store, rooting, 4.4-kitkat, tablet, unknown-sources

About a year ago I rooted my Verizon tablet with King root - which is working fine. Then when Google Play Protect came out, it started giving me this static notification telling me to uninstall King root and it kept on popping up even though I unchecked the "scan apps installed from unknown sources box". It started to annoy me a lot so I just turned off the play store notifications. 
 My question is, is there a way to permanently disable this notification or to somehow "tell" play store that I want to keep the app even though it is potentially harmful?

Comment: Play Store Menu > Play Protect > Scan device for security threats  off. That's all you can do

Comment: as i  mentioned in the question, i _did_  that and it still gave me the notofication